# What could be causing "an item with the same key already exists" error while adding a data source?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datasource

I have a VB.NET WinForms application. While adding a new data source, it is giving "An item with the same already been added" on the Add Data Source wizard form.

The application does not contains any existing data source.

What could possibly be causing this error, and how might I go about resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain the datasource doesn't already exist?  Click on your project in Solution Explorer, click the "Show All Files" button at the top of Solution Explorer, then expand "My Project" and "DataSources."  I suspect you still have a project datasource with the same name.  Keep in mind that deleting a datasource from a control in the designer **does not** remove it from the project.

[image]

Comment: I have rechecked my project. It does not contains any datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, with "Linq server mode source"
When i click on "ElementType", Text box with "An entry with the same key already exists." show up. This nevver happened before and i dont know what to do about that. When i click OK, it shows again and then it works as usual.

[image]